# PHP AND TOMCAT SETUP / integration

Tags: php, tomcat, webserver

Does anyone know a good link or help / steps to undergo to setup PHP (5) on tomcat 6.x ?
I have spend a lot of time on research in the net, downloaded lots, followed steps / tutorials with no success.

Would really appreciate step by step guide, or a link etc. - the stuff I found is usually for older versions - when i download packets, files are missing, which are described in tutorial, and so on..

I assume i need to somehow set up CGI, but have no clue really - thank for any help / hint in this matter

Kind Regards
Alex

Comment: what's wrong with plain and simple apache web server? why tomcat?

Comment: have you tried this one: [Jack Wu - PHP 5 on Tomcat 6 Installation](http://tojackwu.blogspot.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html)? Also, you might to consider migrating this question to serverfault.

Comment: heya, will try the tutorial, but looking at my downloaded folders, i have done this sort of tutorial before (just diff link / page) - will let u know if it works.   And how to I migrate questions to serverfault ? thx regards

Comment: do you want me to supply my comment as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: yes gordon do that, but maybe with a hint of why the php seems to be running but not showing any content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ GORDON

Thank you, your link has worked for me.. > http://tojackwu.blogspot.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html

I tried severall before, but no clue what i made wrong, or what exactly other tutorials been missing out.

I have used PECL 2.2.5 - tomcat 6.0.29 and php 5.2.14  > seems to be very very important which version to use with which..

Best regards alex

Comment: @ gordon, yes - do that, but maybe with a hint of why the php seems to be running but not showing any content