# Best single server solution for GWT, PHP, and SSL

Tags: php, apache, gwt, ssl, tomcat7

So right now I'm rocking Apache 2.2, which I've had running for a couple years (only for local purposes). With Apache, I have PHP 5 installed. Recently I installed Tomcat 7 for Java Servlet support (GWT specifically). I also have Tomcat supports SSL (on a separate port which is annoying but manageable for now).

Here's my problem. GWT cannot use PHP pages and PHP cannot use SSL (unless I install that on Apache). What would be the best solution to get GWT, PHP, and SSL on single server or at least able to interact.

I was thinking maybe install PHP on Tomcat because it already has GWT and SSL ready but a quick Google search didn't show promise on this. Another option I've heard is that Apache can forward certain requests (such as Java Servlets) to Tomcat. I'm hoping someone has a quick answer to save me the headache of Googling.

Also, Apache is running on port XXX1, Tomcat XXX2, and Tomcat SSL XXX3. Is there a way to get these all on a single port? I'm guessing it'd have to be configured at the router/gateway and forwarded to each correct port?

Comment: Why can't they interact?
If it's breaking in development mode, use the -noserver option, when GWT is compiled, it's just pure JavaScript and it should be able to run on anything.

Comment: I'm trying to get them to interact. It's not breaking, it never worked. That's the whole basis of this question. How do you get them to interact. Trying the two solutions provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Apache as a proxy for Tomcat, and have the SSL configured on Apache. You'll need to use mod_proxy for this. A sample configuration would look like this:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat/ http://127.0.0.1:XXX2/
```

You'd then access the Tomcat resources by prefixing a /tomcat/ to the URL path.

Answer (score 1):

Resin is a Java application server with a full PHP5 implementation.

http://quercus.caucho.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just completing the answer given by Jon, take a look to [this configuration](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy) to serve the Tomcat applications from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat, it seems, can run PHP. Found that answer on another [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152341/php-and-tomcat-setup-integration) which points to this handy [tutorial](http://tojackwu.blogspot.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html). I'd still like to know if anyone has another solution?